# Python program to transfer gmail between accounts (including labels)

Tags: python, gmail, google-apps, gmail-imap

The problem, transfer all emails including labels, sent, drafts... from one google apps account to another using python. This seems possible using imap. A complete program would be great :-) but if anyone has some suggestions or examples of how to go about this specific to gmail that would be great.

Comment: What is up with the down votes? A few comments as to what I have done wrong would be helpful.

Comment: I down-voted. I think the question was very vague. You don't seem to have put much effort into the matter and you haven't shown us what have you tried so far. The question is not clear whether you want somebody to build that app for you, or you just want a recommendation, neither it is clear what are the requisites of this app etc. Sorry if this sounded overaggressive, it's not meant to be. I just though it is a bad question for SO.

Comment: Downvotes for poorly asked and vague questions....with a reputation of 252 one can expect better questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used this tool, which can preserve labels:
http://www.gmail-backup.com/

It's written in python.